# (1/1) FatalErrorException Call to a member function all() on null in laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel-5.4

4 and i have a form when submitted i want to validate its fields, what happened is when i submit the form this is what it gets

```
 (1/1) FatalErrorException

Call to a member function all() on null
```

This is my code below

```
$validator = app('validator')->make($this->request->all(),[
            'postTitle' => 'required',
            'postContent' =>'required']);
```

In laravel 5.2 this validator works well but in laravel 5.4 it returns `null`
can someone help me figured this thing out? 
Any help is muchly appreciated. TIA

this is my full code

```
<?php

namespace App\Repositories;
use App\Repositories\Contracts\addPostRepositoryInterface;
use Validator;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use DB;
use Session;
use Hash;

class addPostRepository implements addPostRepositoryInterface{

    protected $request;

    // Intialize request instance
    public function __contruct(Request $request){
        $this->request = $request;
    }


    public function addPosts(Request $request){
        //validate posts
        echo "test";
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'postTitle' => 'required',
            'postContent' =>'required',
        ]);


        //if validation fails return error response
        if($validator->fails())
            return redirect()->route('get.addPost')->withErrors($validator)->withInput();

        try{


        }catch(\Exception $e){
            return redirect()->route('get.addPost')->withErrors(["error"=>"Could not add details! Please try again."])->withInput();
        }


    }


    public function postCreate($screen){
        switch($screen){
            case 'add':
            return $this->addPosts($screen);
            break;
        }
    }

    //getAddPost View
    public function getAddPost(){
        return view('addPost');
    }

}
```

Comment: for test just dd($request) tell me it has contain in addPosts methode before validation section?

Comment: this is the result "add"

Comment: hi can you help me on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems an issue with the method injection (in the constructor) or something.

You may try creating the request object on the local(addPosts()) function.
Please try below alternative solution.

```
<?php

namespace App\Repositories;
use App\Repositories\Contracts\addPostRepositoryInterface;
use Validator;
use DB;
use Session;
use Hash;

class addPostRepository implements addPostRepositoryInterface{


public function addPosts(Request $request){
    //validate posts
    $reqeust = new \Illuminate\Http\Request;

    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'postTitle' => 'required',
        'postContent' =>'required',
    ]);


    //if validation fails return error response
    if($validator->fails())
        return redirect()->route('get.addPost')->withErrors($validator)->withInput();

    try{


    }catch(\Exception $e){
        return redirect()->route('get.addPost')->withErrors(["error"=>"Could not add details! Please try again."])->withInput();
    }


}


public function postCreate($screen){
    switch($screen){
        case 'add':
        return $this->addPosts($screen);
        break;
    }
}

//getAddPost View
public function getAddPost(){
    return view('addPost');
}
// REST OF THE CODE GOES HERE...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Given the information you gave, I will demonstrate you how to validate a request properly in Laravel 5.4

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'postTitle' => 'required',
        'postContent' =>'required',
    ]);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return redirect('your.view')
                    ->withErrors($validator)
                    ->withInput();
    }

    // Store the blog post...
}
```

This will successfully validate the request for you wherever need be. If the validation fails, you will be forwarded to your view with the according errors.

Make sure you `use Validator;` on top of your file.

For more information, you can read up on https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation

Comment: it says  (1/1) FatalErrorException

Class 'App\Repositories\Validator' not found

Comment: did you `use Validator;` or `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
`?

Comment: yes this is what it says 
 (1/1) ErrorException

Undefined variable: request

Comment: are you passing through the request? Show some more code

Comment: if you use `Validator::make($this-request->all()` what is the error message then? Also make sure to edit  `public function addPosts(Request $this->request){`

Comment: i tried this one $validator = Validator::make($this->request->all(), [
   'postTitle' => 'required',
   'postContent' =>'required',
  ]);
error is  (1/1) FatalErrorException

Call to a member function all() on null
with a public function addPosts()

Comment: this is what it says
 (1/1) FatalErrorException

Cannot re-assign $this
when editing this line of code here public function addPosts(Request $this->request)

Comment: Hmmm... what is the output of dd($this->request) and dd($request) if Request $request is passed through?

Comment: i edit into this one 
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
   'postTitle' => 'required',
   'postContent' =>'required',
  ]);
then public function addPosts(Request $request)
the result is this one 
 (1/1) ErrorException

Argument 1 passed to App\Repositories\addPostRepository::addPosts() must be an instance of Illuminate\Http\Request, string given, called in C:\xampp\htdocs\crudlara\app\Repositories\addPostRepository.php on line 49 and defined

Comment: this is the result dd($this->request); null
dd($request) add

Comment: hi can you help me on this?

Comment: if the $request returns null, then there is the issue. You need to make sure that variable gets populated. The code I posted works. In your case I don't really see where the issue is.